# belongsTo vs hasMany in Sequelize.js

Tags: sql, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

What's the difference between `B.belongsTo(A)` and `A.hasMany(B)`

```
Artist = sequelize.define('Artist', {});
Album = sequelize.define('Albums', {});

Album.belongsTo(Artist, foreignKey: 'album_belongsl_artist');
Artist.hasMany(Album, foreignKey: 'artist_hasmany_albums');
```

if it in both cases creates the depended tables in `Album`?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

When you do `Album.belongsTo(Artist)` you are creating the relation enabling you to call `album.getArtist()`.

`Artist.hasMany(Album)` links the association the other way, enabling you to call `artist.getAlbums()`.

If you only did one of those two, e.g. if you only did `Album.belongsTo(Artist)` you would be able to retrieve the artist of an album, but **not** all albums of an artist.

Notice, however, that because of the foreign key given in your example, you are effectively creating two relations. The generated table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Albums` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment , `album_belongsl_artist` INTEGER, `artist_hasmany_albums` INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
```

If you only want one association, the `foreignKey` should be the same.

Example:

```
Album.belongsTo(Artist, {foreignKey: 'artist_id'});
Artist.hasMany(Album,{ foreignKey: 'artist_id'});
```

which generates:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Albums` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment, `artist_id` INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: I'm having a similar issue and I'm just wondering how to get the relation reversely working. I fetched an Artist and call getAlbums on it, which works fine. But then when I use one  Album item from result I've and execute ``getArtists`` on it it's returning just ``null``. How can that be solved? Because the method ``getArtist`` is provided by sequelize.

Comment: @Bernhard You probably need to use the [`include` option](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/model/?highlight=findAll) in the find function call, to specify which model's relations to eagerly load.

Comment: after an hour trawling the docs trying to work out how to do this, your code helped a great deal! got a nice two-way 1:m association now. yay!

Comment: how to implement simple `one-to many` relation.
`db.File.hasMany(db.Like, {foreignKey: 'file_id'})` it's giving me error :`ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'upload_file_tab.file_name' in 'on clause'`

Comment: @UmairAhmed it is best to ask this as a separate question

Comment: Is it possible to add both relations? Or will this cause any conflicts?

Comment: Shouldn't it be like this; note `foreignKey` value is **artist_id** (vs **album_id**):
`Album.belongsTo(Artist, {foreignKey: 'artist_id'});` just like the Sequelize documentation has `City.belongsTo(Country, {foreignKey: 'countryCode' })`. In other words, the function `belongsTo`  is ...

1) called *on* the model/table which  adds a *referencing* column (i.e. the source; Album , or City) 

2)  called *with* the model/table which has the *referenced* ID (Artist, or Country) 

3)  called with the `foreignKey` , the name of the column pointing from #1 to #2 (artist_id, countryCode)

Comment: shouldn't both statements have foreignKey: 'artist_id' ? as 1 artist has many albums and the idea is that the FKs are the same

Comment: so in any case putting both belongsTo and hasMany would enable internal methods from Sequelize but the resulting table would be the same with one of them, is this correct?

Comment: Yes, both foreign keys should be `artist_id`. The answer itself states "the foreignKey should be the same". https://sequelize.org/master/manual/associations.html#one-to-many-associations--hasmany-. This mistake was overlooked, the pair of associations' foreign keys have to share the same name for it to work. Both should be `artist_id` instead of both being `album_id` because the parent artist hasMany child albums, FK is stored with the child.

Comment: Both were originally artist_id until the post was edited incorrectly. I've submitted a new edit (pending review) to undo that.

Comment: why is this thing overly complicated? why cant you just say table B has a foreign key to table A instead of doing all this hasMany belongsTo stuff